# How to create a multi-dimension array generator?

Tags: java

I'm trying to generate a multi-dimensional array which works upon the random integers generated. I'm unable to do so because it doesn't work properly.

```
public class Gen(){
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int randomRow, randomCol;

        int[][] array1 = new int[61][50];

        for(int row = 0; row < array1.length; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < array1.length; col++){
                randomRow = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 100);
                randomCol = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 100);
                array1[row][col] = array1[randomRow][randomCol];
                System.out.println(array1[row][col] + "/n");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

But this does not work. Any reason why?

Comment: What is the output?  How is it different than what you expect?

Comment: While in this case it may be obvious for an experienced programmer that there are problems with the code, @GarchyBoy, you are really supposed to give precise statements of the *expected* and the *actual* outcome of the code you are asking about. For better answers, you can do yourself a favour by studying the help section before your next question.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* what you are trying to do is put random numbers between 0 and 99 in an array. Is that correct? If so:

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
        array[i][j] = 1 + random.nextInt(100);
```

Note that if you are using Java 8 then there is a simpler technique to generate an array of random integers than assigning a random value to each position:

```
array[] = random.ints(60, 1, 101).toArray();
```

Comment: It should probably be `1 + random.nextInt(100)` so you get a number in the range from 1 through 100 as in the question.

Comment: @OleV.V. Agree. have edited to match.

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
for(int col = 0; col < array1[0].length; col++){
```

**BUT**

This is not safe

```
array1[row][col] = array1[randomRow][randomCol];
```

as randomRow maybe be up to 100, but the array is only 61

similar problem for randomCol

**But** really what are you trying to do.  The values in this array are all 0, so reassigning that value of one index to another ain't going to achieve anything.

**Edit**

Based upon the below comments it seems you are wanting to fill your array with random numbers then that can be achieved by @sprinters answer

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++)
        array[i][j] = 1 + random.nextInt(100);
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a 2D array with randomly generated numbers. Why would randomRow being up to 100 be a problem? That's the assigned value for array1[row] for some row. How can I assign randomRow to array1[row] for some [row]?

Comment: Thanks, @GarchyBoy, this is the information that we would have liked to have in the question from the outset. :-) It would have been so much easier to help you. :-)

Comment: In your code you do `array1[randomRow][randomCol]`, this tries to take out the value from an array element. The problems with that seem to be two, if I understand correctly (1) this was not your intension (2) if randomRow >= 61 or randomCol >= 50, this is a non-existing array element, and your program will crash with an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @OleV.V. I guess you are replying to the OP - correct?  Anyway, thank you for expanding on the point made in my answer.  To the OP I would like to point out that a way to achieve what you are wanting has been added to my answer.

Comment: Yes, @ScaryWombat, you are correct, that was my attempt to answer @GarchyBoy’s question “Why would randomRow being up to 100 be a problem?” Sorry that that was unclear.

Comment: @sprinter You are absolutely right - Sorry for my oversight

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks for that. I'll delete my comment to avoid confusing people who read your current answer.